# Cust google custom search "No Result" string to link

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm using google CSE in my site. But I want to change the "No Result" string to a link, or redirect the page when no search result.

I tried `noResultsString` attribute but it accept String only. How can I use HTML Tag like`<gcse:searchresults noResultsString="<a src='testSrc'>no-result link</a>"></gcse:searchresults>`? Or can I redirect the result page when no-result?

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript, then specify names or ids then the functions if there is no results.
Here is an intro tutorial  that does not specify an id relating to your case, but is using timers for a redirect http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_page_redirect.htm

Comment: setTimeout and redirect is not good ideal for my case. I want some event like `onSearchComplite`, but I cant find that in CSE api v2.

Comment: @user2297525 There is some callback information here:  https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element?hl=fr  I don't know if that initialization callback is what you need, but I think it is.  To then determine the results, look for your "not found" text with JavaScript, and then perform whatever action you need.

Comment: @Brad I tried `callback` but it's work like `onSearchReady`, not a call back after search.